# как закрепить div внизу страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, css

На главной странице (header на весь экран) есть стрелка которая как бы указывает что надо скроллить, ее нужно закрепить внизу экрана (секции header)

Comment: Ок, а в чём проблема-то? Если можете — закрепляйте, если не можете — расскажите как вы пытались, покажите код.

Comment: Если кто-нибудь своим ответом-таки решил вашу проблему, то не поленитесь отметить ответ "галочкой" (рядом со "стрелочками" у ответов), чтобы он не висел в списке неотвеченных :)

Answer (score 1):

Вот так вот?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.header {
  height: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  position: relative;
}
.arrow {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #aaa;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  /* Центрирование */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.block {
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">

  <div class="arrow"></div>
</header>

<div class="block"></div>
```

Или если надо чтобы стрелка была привязана не к блоку, а к экрану:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.block {
  height: 100%;
}
.b1 {
  background: #eee;
}
.b2 {
  background: #ccc;
}
.arrow {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #aaa;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  /* Центрирование */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="block b1"></div>
<div class="block b2"></div>

<div class="arrow"></div>
```